# Tab View blocking UIPageControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to swift and have implemented a PageViewController.  However I am trying to show the Page Control (aka dots at the bottom indicating you can swipe left or right how many times) but I believe it is blocked by my Tab Bar Controller I have over all the views of the application.  Is there a way to edit where the UIPageControl appears so it appears right above the Tabs at the bottom?  I included my UIPageControl setup below which is called when the view for this tab loads on viewDidLoad().

```
private func setupPageControl() {
        let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    }
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
setupPageControl()

let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as! UIPageViewController
pageController.dataSource = self

if contentImages.count > 0 {
    let firstController = getItemController(0)!
    let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
    pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

}

pageViewController = pageController
addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

[image: Story board image]

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?